# How to dynamically import data in a nodejs app?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, express, ejs

I would like to use require in a node/express app with typescript to import a json. I tried it like this:

```
const url = `./data/${resource}.json`;
const data = require(url);
```

but I get the error `Cannot find module './data/my-data.json'`.

I'd like to use require instead of an import in order to create the data variable dynamically depending on the value of the resource variable.

Comment: The most likely cause for your problem is the file path to your JSON file relative to your calling code. Can you verify and post the directory structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const path = require('path');
const url = path.resolve(__dirname, `./data/${resource}.json`);   
const data = require(url);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

<s>The require keyword is a special keyword in nodejs. It is used to load modules, and since your json file is not a module, hence the error. Try this, this way you can dynamically load your json.</s>

```
import fs from 'fs';
const file = fs.readFileSync(`./data/${resource}.json`).toString();
const data = JSON.parse(file);
```

There may be better ways to write this function, read mode about the fs module [here.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

---

**Edit:** As someone had alredy pointed out, it is actually possible to dynamically`require` json file. Here's how,

```
import path from 'path';
const uri = path.resolve(__dirname, `<path_to_json_file>`);   
const data = require(uri);
```

However, as a standard practice, use the `fs` module to load static assets to your project.

Answer (score -4):

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const file = fs.readFileSync(`./data/${resource}.json`).toString();
const data = JSON.parse(file);
```

Comment: This answer is not only incorrect, it parrots an answer given 10 hours earlier